# Keep Constant Columns h2o

Tags: r, machine-learning, h2o, gbm

I'm trying to implement a gradient boosting machine model using R's h2o package. However, the model keeps dropping a certain column that I know from other model build ups that this column is important.

```
 Warning message:
    In .h2o.startModelJob(algo, params, h2oRestApiVersion) :
      Dropping bad and constant columns:['mycolumn']
```

How do I stop h2o from dropping this column? Here is what I tried:

```
gbm_fit<-h2o.gbm(x,y,train_set,nfolds = 10,
                 ntrees = 250,
                 learn_rate = 0.15,
                 max_depth = 7,
                             validation_frame = validate_set,seed = 233,
                ignore_const_cols = F
                )
```

Comment: Is the column constant? If so could you please elaborate how a constant column has any predictive/explanatory value.

Comment: The column is "constant" with two levels let's call them "Senior" and "Junior". I built models using caret and this column had the greatest impact on performance. I therefore think it should not be dropped.

Comment: Then it is not constant, but binary. What is the class of that column?

Comment: That solved it. Thanks!

Comment: how have you solved this problem? have you set a specific class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the column class is correct and accepted by the function.

Comment: I've since solved it thanks to your previous comments.

Comment: How is it solved ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed all character columns to factor and this solved the issue. I am using `h2o.automl`